# JS function to iterate through object and print only the value of particular key returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object

```
{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
      "nodeDataArray": [ 
    {"isGroup":true, "key":-1, "text":"SP", "xy":"-5 269.225"},
    {"isGroup":true, "key":-2, "text":"DM", "xy":"300 243.26562500000003"},
    {"key":100, "Data":"device", "group":-2},
    {"key":101, "Data":"name : Device1", "group":-2},
    {"key":102, "Data":"config", "group":-2},
    {"key":103, "Data":"interface", "group":-2},
    {"key":104, "Data":"Loopback", "group":-2},
    {"key":105, "Data":"name : {loopback-intf}", "group":-2},
    {"key":106, "Data":"description", "group":-2},
    {"key":107, "Data":"_tags : merge", "group":-2},
    {"key":108, "Data":"__text : Loopback{loopback-intf}", "group":-2},
    {"key":109, "Data":"ip", "group":-2},
    {"key":110, "Data":"address", "group":-2},
    {"key":111, "Data":"primary", "group":-2},
    {"key":112, "Data":"address : {ip-address}", "group":-2},
    {"key":113, "Data":"mask : 255.255.255.255", "group":-2},
    {"key":114, "Data":"_xmlns : http://someweb.org", "group":-2},
    {"key":115, "Data":"_tags : merge", "group":-2},
    {"key":116, "Data":"Loopback", "group":-2},
    {"key":117, "Data":"name : {loopback-intf}", "group":-2},
    {"key":118, "Data":"description", "group":-2},
    {"key":119, "Data":"_tags : merge", "group":-2},
    {"key":120, "Data":"__text : Loopback{loopback-intf}", "group":-2},
    {"key":121, "Data":"ip", "group":-2},
    {"key":122, "Data":"address", "group":-2},
    {"key":123, "Data":"primary", "group":-2},
    {"key":124, "Data":"address : {ip-address}", "group":-2},
    {"key":125, "Data":"mask : 255.255.255.255", "group":-2},
    {"key":126, "Data":"_xmlns : http://sometest.org", "group":-2},
    {"key":127, "Data":"_tags : merge", "group":-2},
    {"key":0, "Data":"container car", "group":-1},
    {"key":1, "Data":"container v8_engine", "group":-1},
    {"key":2, "Data":"leaf-list cylinder-arrangement", "group":-1},
    {"key":3, "Data":"type string", "group":-1},
    {"key":4, "Data":"max-elements 8", "group":-1},
    {"key":5, "Data":"container other-parts", "group":-1},
    {"key":6, "Data":"list per-cylinder-parts", "group":-1},
    {"key":7, "Data":"leaf piston-diameter", "group":-1},
    {"key":8, "Data":"type uint32", "group":-1},
    {"key":9, "Data":"range 2000... 9000", "group":-1},
    {"key":10, "Data":"container valves", "group":-1},
    {"key":11, "Data":"leaf number", "group":-1},
    {"key":12, "Data":"list position", "group":-1},
    {"key":13, "Data":"type change", "group":-1}
     ],
      "linkDataArray": [ 
    {"from":100, "to":101},
    {"from":100, "to":102},
    {"from":102, "to":103},
    {"from":103, "to":104},
    {"from":104, "to":105},
    {"from":104, "to":106},
    {"from":106, "to":107},
    {"from":106, "to":108},
    {"from":104, "to":109},
    {"from":109, "to":110},
    {"from":110, "to":111},
    {"from":111, "to":112},
    {"from":111, "to":113},
    {"from":103, "to":114},
    {"from":103, "to":115},
    {"from":103, "to":116},
    {"from":116, "to":117},
    {"from":116, "to":118},
    {"from":118, "to":119},
    {"from":118, "to":120},
    {"from":116, "to":121},
    {"from":121, "to":122},
    {"from":122, "to":123},
    {"from":123, "to":124},
    {"from":123, "to":125},
    {"from":103, "to":126},
    {"from":103, "to":127},
    {"from":0, "to":1},
    {"from":1, "to":2},
    {"from":2, "to":3},
    {"from":2, "to":4},
    {"from":0, "to":5},
    {"from":5, "to":6},
    {"from":6, "to":7},
    {"from":7, "to":8},
    {"from":7, "to":9},
    {"from":6, "to":10},
    {"from":10, "to":11},
    {"from":10, "to":12},
    {"from":5, "to":13},
    {"category":"Mapping", "from":4, "to":116},
    {"category":"Mapping", "from":6, "to":104},
    {"category":"Mapping", "from":9, "to":116},
    {"category":"Mapping", "from":12, "to":109}
     ]}
```

This is my input object which i would like to read through and look for the following "category":"Mapping" and then create an array as shown below

```
category:[{a:4,b:116},{a:6,b:104},{a:9,b:116},{a:12,b:109}]
```

but even the simple code

```
console.log(data.linkData.Array);
```

gives output as undefined.

Note: if i pass this data hard coded like var data= that object, it works perfectly but the same array i assign it dynamically and try accessing the element , i get unassigned. Not sure whats causing it :(

i have also tried the following

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedDiagramModel));
```

and then access the data but no luck

Comment: You should probably post the JS code that you're using to iterate through this object.

Comment: The idea here is you show the code you tried that didn't work,not for us to write it all for you from scratch

Comment: Is `category` supposed to be a property of the `data` object? Should it replace all other `{"category": "Mapping", `…`}` objects in `data.linkDataArray`? As far as I can see you only need those `{"category": "Mapping", `…`}` objects in order to create your desired array — is this correct?

Comment: `for(var prop in data){ }` doesn’t do anything. Of course you had no success with it. Where’s your actual attempt?

Comment: Actually speaking the issue seems to be something with the dynamic data that is coming up.  I am not sure whats causing it when i try my logic or any of the functions below with the data being assigned it works but if i assign an dynamic json and use this logic, i get Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

This will to the filtering and mapping to get your desired outcome:

```
var result = data.linkDataArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.category;
}).map(function(item) {
    return {a: item.from, b: item.to};
});


/*
[{
  a: 4,
  b: 116
}, {
  a: 6,
  b: 104
}, {
  a: 9,
  b: 116
}, {
  a: 12,
  b: 109
}]
*/
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/haxidaj/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in pure Javascript:

```
var category = [];
for (var i=0; i < data.linkDataArray.length; i++) {
    var o = data.linkDataArray[i];

    if (typeof(o.category) !== 'undefined') category.push({ a:o.from, b:o.to });
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. But still i get the error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. not sure whats wrong with the format of dynamic data. strange part is if i copy the same data and provide as hardcoded value to data and run these function it works.

Comment: You probably need to post all of your code...something is going wrong building your array.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with dynamic data.

so i had to add the below line before parsing the object.

```
let jsonObject =JSON.parse(savedDiagramModel);
```

then add an function that parses through linkDataArray and then creates an object as required.